# ggMarginal two-group boxplots are different widths when they shouldn't be

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to add groupwise boxplots to the margins using ggMarginal, but I can't for the life of me get them to be the same widths. What am I missing here?

Example:

```
scatterplotMPG = ggplot( data=mpg, aes(x=cty, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(data=mpg[mpg$drv%in%c('r', 'f'), ], aes(color=factor(drv)), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(data=mpg[mpg$drv%in%c('4'), ], color='gray', alpha=0.3)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

ggExtra::ggMarginal(scatterplotMPG, type = "boxplot",
                    groupFill = TRUE, groupColour = TRUE, size=7,
                    xparams = list(varwidth = FALSE),
                    yparams = list(varwidth = FALSE))
```

[image: r and f groups are different sizes]

I have tried passing no x/yparams, setting width to an integer value, and setting varwidth to FALSE (as in the above code). All produce the same plot.

**edit**:
I still haven't been able to get this working with ggMarginal and would love a solution, but in the meantime, I was able to manually construct what I want using patchwork (where xAxisBoxPlot and yAxisBoxPlot are boxplot objects):

```
combinedPointPlot <- wrap_plots(
  xAxisBoxPlot,
  plot_spacer(),
  scatterplotMPG,
  yAxisBoxPlot,
  nrow = 2,
  widths = c(1, 0.05),
  heights = c(0.05, 1)
) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = 'Primary Title',
    theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18)))
```

with a theme applied to the two boxplots to strip away unneeded components:

```
theme_marginal <- theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                        panel.border = element_blank(),
                        plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "pt"),
                        legend.position = "none")
```